# Change Value of one Control through MouseDown event of another

Tags: wpf, binding, controls

I have two custom controls in wpf. One is Chart control and other is Circular Progress bar. Chart control has following relevant code.

```
>    public int BarValue { get; set; }
>    private void DrawData()
>         {
>             string data = File.ReadAllText(DataSource);
>             string[] valueData = data.Split(';');
>             string[] strValues = valueData[0].Split(',');
>             string[] strYear = valueData[1].Split(',');
>             double section = 525 / strValues.Length;
>             rectSpace = (section * 20) / 100;
>             rectWidth = (section * 80) / 100;
>          
> 
>             for (int i = 0; i < strYear.Length; i++)
>             {
>                
>                 Rectangle rec = new Rectangle();
>                 rec.Width = rectWidth;
>                rec.Height = Convert.ToDouble(strValues[i]);
>         
>                 rec.Margin = new Thickness((rectSpace), (350 - rec.Height), 
>     0,25);
>                 rec.Fill = BarsColor;
>                 panel.Children.Add(rec); rec.MouseDown += Rec_MouseDown; }  
     private void Rec_MouseDown(object sender,
>     MouseButtonEventArgs e)
>         {
>             BarValue =Convert.ToInt32( ((Rectangle)sender).Height);
>         }
```

Then the ProgressBar has a property Value. 
I added both controls to MainWindow. If i click on one rectangle which is an mouseDown event as provided above, how i can change valueproperty of ProgressBar.
I tried

> `progCircle.Value = chart.BarValue;`

in the mainWindow constructor. Not Working.
Any Idea.. Thanks

xml-Main

```
<Grid Margin="1,0,-318,-30" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  Width="1418">
        <Rectangle x:Name="MainRec" RadiusX="9" RadiusY="9" Margin="25,38,425,51" Opacity="0.75">
            <Rectangle.Fill>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF0F2A3C" Offset="1"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Rectangle.Fill>
        </Rectangle>
        <Rectangle x:Name="TitleBar" Fill="#FF070E17" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="40" Margin="25,38,0,0" RadiusY="9" RadiusX="9" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="968" Opacity="0.75" MouseDown="TitleBar_MouseDown"/>
        <Label Content="Wools Valley" Foreground="Wheat" Margin="43,42,1225,565" Width="150" Height="30" FontSize="14"/>
        <Ellipse x:Name="closeButton" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="20" Margin="960,52,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="20" MouseDown="closeButton_MouseDown"  Opacity="0.7" ToolTip="Close" RenderTransformOrigin="4.851,0.607">
            <Ellipse.Fill>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="DarkCyan"  Offset="0"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="1"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Ellipse.Fill>
            <Ellipse.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="UIElement.MouseEnter">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="closeButton"
                                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" 
                                             From="0.7" To="1" Duration="0:0:1"/>
                        </Storyboard>

                    </BeginStoryboard>



      </EventTrigger>

    </Ellipse.Triggers>

</Ellipse>

<BarGraph2:BarGraph x:Name="bargraph" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="425" Margin="79,99,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="654" DataSource="D:\\data3.txt" BarsColor="DarkCyan" AxisValueColor="Cyan" titleText="GDP Comparision" />
<ControlExamplesVS:ProgressCircle x:Name="progCircle" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="185" Margin="760,99,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="184" IndicatorBrush="Cyan" BackgroundBrush="Transparent" ProgressBorderBrush="DarkCyan"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: give an alement name to your chart control and bind the value of the ProgressBar to that element :  Value = "{Binding ElementName=chart, Path=Value}". Do this in xaml of course. Or if you are using CodeBehind you have to build manually the binding in the main window code behind

Comment: The mousedown event of dynamically created rectangles (bars) in chart control is supposed to trigger the binding and change the value of circularprogressbar. Can you give me a bit explanation considering that? Thanks

Comment: As soon as BarValue change, then, change also the value of ProgCirle.Value since it's binded to it. So if BarValue change on MouseDown event, it will change the value of the progress bar too. In my answer i provided 2 way to implement it, using xaml or code behind

Comment: Also consider that you can do the same using a viewmodel. You just need to set the Binding and you are done

Comment: i put the code you provided in constructor. But when i click on a rectangle, progressbar value is not updating.

Comment: panel is your Chart? Where did you placed the ProgressBar? Do you have one progressBar for each rectangle or only one global progressbar?

Comment: Chart is separate control comprise of grid,stackpanel,wrappanel. ProgressBar is separate. I added both controls to mainWindow through xml (drag and drop).

Comment: Can you show me Xaml of main window + the code you took from my answer?

Comment: <BarGraph2:BarGraph x:Name="bargraph" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="425" Margin="79,99,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="654" DataSource="D:\\data3.txt" BarsColor="DarkCyan" AxisValueColor="Cyan" titleText="GDP Comparision" />                                  
        <ControlExamplesVS:ProgressCircle x:Name="progCircle" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="185" Margin="760,99,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="184" IndicatorBrush="Cyan" BackgroundBrush="Transparent" ProgressBorderBrush="DarkCyan" Value="{Binding ElementName=bargraph,Path=BarValue}"/>

Comment: try to add UpdtateSourceTrigger = PropertyChanged on the binding of the Value property of ProgressCircle

Comment: <ControlExamplesVS:ProgressCircle x:Name="progCircle" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="185" Margin="760,99,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="184" IndicatorBrush="Cyan" BackgroundBrush="Transparent" ProgressBorderBrush="DarkCyan" Value="{Binding ElementName=bargraph,Path=BarValue,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>                              Not Working Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it in code behind, add this piece of code after you added your controls in the MainWindow:

```
Binding bind= new Binding();
bind.Source = chart;
bind.Path = new PropertyPath("BarValue");
bind.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
bind.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;
BindingOperations.SetBinding(progCircle, CircuòarProgressBar.ValueProperty, bind);
```

If you have them already in xaml instead you can simply do the following:

```
<CircularProgressBar Value="{Binding ElementName = chart, Path = Value}"/>
<Chart x:Name = "chart"/>
```